# Matlab undefined variable or function "out"

Tags: matlab

I have this code in MATLAB:

```
function [out,f]  = rec_det(a,n)


if(n==2)

 out = a(1,1)*a(2,2)-a(2,1)*a(1,2);



else

for j=1:n
     f = a(1,j);
     a(1,:) = [];
     a(:,3) = [];
     out = out +  ((-1)^(1+n)*f* rec_det(a,n-1));





end

end
```

And I get a error in this line" out = out +  ((-1)^(1+n)*f* rec_det(a,n-1));".The error says "undefined function of variable out" but I dont get why this is happening.

I'm very new to MATLAB so please be patient with me.

Comment: It's in an `else` block. So it hasn't been initialized yet. The first time the `out=out+...` is called, the initial value is not known. You need to initialize it before the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```matlab
    function [out,f] = rec_det(a,n)

    if(n==2)
        out = a(1,1)*a(2,2)-a(2,1)*a(1,2);
    else
        s = 0;
        for j=1:n
           f = a(1,j);
           a(1,:) = [];
           a(:,3) = [];
           s = s +  ((-1)^(1+n)*f* rec_det(a,n-1));
        end
        out = s;
    end
```

Comment: Probably won't work for `n == 2`.